# Adding bullet before statement in powerpoint via officer in R

Tags: r, formatting, officer

I am using the `officer` package in R to create reproducible slides. I can add bullets in front of sentences without problem when the sentences are places in the "body" object of the powerpoint template, but when I try to assign the exact location of the sentence, no bullets are included. Please see the script as below:

```
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

pptx.output.st00 <- read_pptx()

pptx.content1 <- c('sample sentence #1',
                   'sample sentence #2',
                   'sample sentence #3')

pptx.content2 <- block_list(fpar(ftext(c('sample sentence #1'),
                                       prop = fp_text(font.family = 'Calibri',font.size=32))),
                            fpar(ftext(c('sample sentence #2'),
                                       prop = fp_text(font.family = 'Calibri',font.size=32))),
                            fpar(ftext(c('sample sentence #3'),
                                       prop = fp_text(font.family = 'Calibri',font.size=32))))

pptx.output.st01 <- pptx.output.st00 %>%
  add_slide(.,layout = 'Title and Content',master = 'Office Theme') %>%
  ph_with(.,value='Background',location=ph_location_type(type='title')) %>%
  ph_with(.,value=pptx.content1,location=ph_location_type(type='body',id = 1)) %>%
  ph_with(.,value=pptx.content2,location=ph_location(left = 0.5,top = 5.25,width = 8.5,height = 2))

print(pptx.output.st01,'presentation.output.pptx')
```

I wonder if bullet can also be assigned when the sentences are placed using `ph_location` instead of `ph_location_type`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help.

- ph_location_template: need to be used so that we can reuse properties from *body* (body has associated bullets in properties)
- if used, `level_list` mean to add bullets for each paragraph to add

```
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

pptx.output.st00 <- read_pptx()

pptx.content1 <- c('sample sentence #1',
                   'sample sentence #2',
                   'sample sentence #3')

pptx.content2 <- block_list(fpar(ftext(c('sample sentence #1'),
                                       prop = fp_text(font.family = 'Calibri',font.size=32))),
                            fpar(ftext(c('sample sentence #2'),
                                       prop = fp_text(font.family = 'Calibri',font.size=32))),
                            fpar(ftext(c('sample sentence #3'),
                                       prop = fp_text(font.family = 'Calibri',font.size=32))))

pptx.output.st01 <- pptx.output.st00 %>%
  add_slide(.,layout = 'Title and Content',master = 'Office Theme') %>%
  ph_with(.,value='Background',location=ph_location_type(type='title')) %>%
  ph_with(.,value=pptx.content1,location=ph_location_type(type='body',id = 1)) %>%

  ph_with(.,value=pptx.content2,
          location = ph_location_template(left = 0.5,top = 5.25,width = 8.5,height = 2, type="body"),
          level_list = 1:3)

print(pptx.output.st01,'presentation.output.pptx')
```

[image]