# Adding ordered list instead of unorder list in powerpoint by officer

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

This is a followup question on top of [Adding bullet before statement in powerpoint via officer in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170294/adding-bullet-before-statement-in-powerpoint-via-officer-in-r)

The script below is able to create a powerpoint slide with bullets, what if I want to insert a numbered list instead of bullet? I am aware of the `unordered_list` function, I wonder if there is an equivalent `ordered_list` function.

```
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

pptx.output.st00 <- read_pptx()

pptx.content1 <- c('sample sentence #1',
                   'sample sentence #2',
                   'sample sentence #3')

pptx.content2 <- block_list(fpar(ftext(c('sample sentence #1'),
                                       prop = fp_text(font.family = 'Calibri',font.size=32))),
                            fpar(ftext(c('sample sentence #2'),
                                       prop = fp_text(font.family = 'Calibri',font.size=32))),
                            fpar(ftext(c('sample sentence #3'),
                                       prop = fp_text(font.family = 'Calibri',font.size=32))))

pptx.output.st01 <- pptx.output.st00 %>%
  add_slide(.,layout = 'Title and Content',master = 'Office Theme') %>%
  ph_with(.,value='Background',location=ph_location_type(type='title')) %>%
  ph_with(.,value=pptx.content1,location=ph_location_type(type='body',id = 1)) %>%

  ph_with(.,value=pptx.content2,
          location = ph_location_template(left = 0.5,top = 5.25,width = 8.5,height = 2, type="body"),
          level_list = 1:3)

print(pptx.output.st01,'presentation.output.pptx')
```